# Changing number of columns dynamically in Bootstrap grids

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a layout for desktop browsers and other layout for tablet browsers.

I want to see 3+9 columns in desktop browsers  (3 for sidebar and 9 for content),  and 12 columns (only content) in tablets.
I don´t need the sidebar in tablets, so I need show fluid content in that case (width 100%)

I wrote this code and it works fine with desktop browser, but when I test it in a tablet browser I see only 9 columns.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

```
...
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span3 visible-desktop">
          <!-- Render Sidebar -->
       </div>
       <div class="span9">
          <!-- Render Content-->
       </div>
    </div>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this at the end of your css:

```
@media (max-width: 979px){
  .span9 {width: 100% !important;}
```

}

You may want to add an additional class to that span such as 'content', and change the rule to target '.content' verus '.span9'

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](https://github.com/barraq/sass-twitter-bootstrap/tree/master/demos/fluid-grid-demo-1) and the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/mootools/1.4.5/barraq/sass-twitter-bootstrap/tree/master/demos/fluid-grid-demo-1/) of doing so without adding Bootstrap markup to your html document.

demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sass Bootstrap - Fluid Grid - demo 1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-body" class="hero-unit">
            <article>
                <header><h1>Article Title</h1></header>
                <section class="main">
                    <header><h2>Section Title</h2></header>
                    Laborum eveniet cupiditate qui placeat adipisci dolor itaque porro corporis, quae expedita quis sint quas eveniet voluptatum velit, magnam alias totam architecto possimus porro? Dolores ex tempora ipsam earum architecto hic vel, rem ducimus praesentium fugit quisquam veniam, esse itaque quos eligendi aut labore tempora. Quidem magni soluta. Odit reiciendis repellat laudantium corrupti totam provident, eveniet cumque similique voluptatum obcaecati fugit perspiciatis vero in, animi facere neque ipsam iure sequi quo minus illum magni aliquam odio, nemo officiis eius aut dolor consequuntur blanditiis adipisci perferendis non nostrum?
Delectus rem atque possimus vel voluptate, hic ipsa ea eligendi inventore suscipit, inventore architecto consectetur officia illum aperiam labore totam dicta. Fugiat ut consequuntur sunt minima, ducimus excepturi iure et sed voluptas hic minima corporis, accusantium architecto quo laudantium blanditiis ullam voluptas in laborum sit? Est magni sapiente iusto quia vitae, vitae molestiae iste? Tempore expedita maiores.
Corporis nulla inventore tenetur tempore?
Nesciunt itaque nam ipsum voluptate quos impedit facere id. Saepe quibusdam maiores optio id natus ut quas pariatur.
Quas tenetur tempore mollitia eius provident quidem ea quam ut et, corporis beatae iure error eligendi possimus maiores ipsum numquam, enim fuga cumque blanditiis eius id excepturi ut quia iusto hic quisquam, commodi incidunt pariatur. Aliquid consequatur nostrum maiores veniam magnam tenetur aperiam quis, dignissimos in tenetur explicabo ea ratione provident corrupti necessitatibus eveniet iure autem, ullam possimus ea natus ipsam.
Minus unde totam aliquid natus quis, eos ullam autem pariatur ducimus quibusdam iste, cum ab quasi iusto ut culpa quam illum hic laboriosam
                </section>
                <section>
                    <section>
                    <header><h2>Section Title</h2></header>
                    Laborum eveniet cupiditate qui placeat adipisci dolor itaque porro corporis, quae expedita quis sint quas eveniet voluptatum velit, magnam alias totam architecto possimus porro? Dolores ex tempora ipsam earum architecto hic vel, rem ducimus praesentium fugit quisquam veniam, esse itaque quos eligendi aut labore tempora. Quidem magni soluta. Odit reiciendis repellat laudantium corrupti totam provident, eveniet cumque similique voluptatum obcaecati fugit perspiciatis vero in, animi facere neque ipsam iure sequi quo minus illum magni aliquam odio, nemo officiis eius aut dolor consequuntur blanditiis adipisci perferendis non nostrum?
Delectus rem atque possimus vel voluptate, hic ipsa ea eligendi inventore suscipit, inventore architecto consectetur officia illum aperiam labore totam dicta. Fugiat ut consequuntur sunt minima, ducimus excepturi iure et sed voluptas hic minima corporis, accusantium architecto quo laudantium blanditiis ullam voluptas in laborum sit? Est magni sapiente iusto quia vitae, vitae molestiae iste? Tempore expedita maiores.
Corporis nulla inventore tenetur tempore?
Nesciunt itaque nam ipsum voluptate quos impedit facere id. Saepe quibusdam maiores optio id natus ut quas pariatur.
Quas tenetur tempore mollitia eius provident quidem ea quam ut et, corporis beatae iure error eligendi possimus maiores ipsum numquam, enim fuga cumque blanditiis eius id excepturi ut quia iusto hic quisquam, commodi incidunt pariatur. Aliquid consequatur nostrum maiores veniam magnam tenetur aperiam quis, dignissimos in tenetur explicabo ea ratione provident corrupti necessitatibus eveniet iure autem, ullam possimus ea natus ipsam.
Minus unde totam aliquid natus quis, eos ullam autem pariatur ducimus quibusdam iste, cum ab quasi iusto ut culpa quam illum hic laboriosam
                    </section>
                    <section>
                    <header><h2>Section Title</h2></header>
                    Laborum eveniet cupiditate qui placeat adipisci dolor itaque porro corporis, quae expedita quis sint quas eveniet voluptatum velit, magnam alias totam architecto possimus porro? Dolores ex tempora ipsam earum architecto hic vel, rem ducimus praesentium fugit quisquam veniam, esse itaque quos eligendi aut labore tempora. Quidem magni soluta. Odit reiciendis repellat laudantium corrupti totam provident, eveniet cumque similique voluptatum obcaecati fugit perspiciatis vero in, animi facere neque ipsam iure sequi quo minus illum magni aliquam odio, nemo officiis eius aut dolor consequuntur blanditiis adipisci perferendis non nostrum?
Delectus rem atque possimus vel voluptate, hic ipsa ea eligendi inventore suscipit, inventore architecto consectetur officia illum aperiam labore totam dicta. Fugiat ut consequuntur sunt minima, ducimus excepturi iure et sed voluptas hic minima corporis, accusantium architecto quo laudantium blanditiis ullam voluptas in laborum sit? Est magni sapiente iusto quia vitae, vitae molestiae iste? Tempore expedita maiores.
Corporis nulla inventore tenetur tempore?
Nesciunt itaque nam ipsum voluptate quos impedit facere id. Saepe quibusdam maiores optio id natus ut quas pariatur.
Quas tenetur tempore mollitia eius provident quidem ea quam ut et, corporis beatae iure error eligendi possimus maiores ipsum numquam, enim fuga cumque blanditiis eius id excepturi ut quia iusto hic quisquam, commodi incidunt pariatur. Aliquid consequatur nostrum maiores veniam magnam tenetur aperiam quis, dignissimos in tenetur explicabo ea ratione provident corrupti necessitatibus eveniet iure autem, ullam possimus ea natus ipsam.
Minus unde totam aliquid natus quis, eos ullam autem pariatur ducimus quibusdam iste, cum ab quasi iusto ut culpa quam illum hic laboriosam
                    </section>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div id="page-sidebar" class="well">
            <div class="section">
                <ul>
                    <li>menu1</li>
                    <li>menu2</li>
                    <li>menu3</li>
                    <li>menu4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

demo.scss:

```
@import "../../lib/bootstrap.scss";
@import "../../lib/responsive.scss";

// body is the fluid containter
body { @extend .container-fluid; }

// make elements "column fluid"
#page-body, 
#page-sidebar {
    @extend [class*="span"];
}
section:not(.main) > section {
    @extend [class*="span"];
    @media (max-width: 1199px) { margin-left: 0 !important; }
}

// make elements "row fluid"
#page,
#page > section:not(.main) {
    @extend .row-fluid;
}

// responsive grid
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #page-body { @include grid-fluid-span(7, $fluidGridColumnWidth768, $fluidGridGutterWidth768); }
    #page-sidebar { @include grid-fluid-span(5, $fluidGridColumnWidth768, $fluidGridGutterWidth768); }
}

@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #page-body { @include grid-fluid-span(7, $fluidGridColumnWidth, $fluidGridGutterWidth); }
    #page-sidebar { @include grid-fluid-span(5, $fluidGridColumnWidth, $fluidGridGutterWidth); }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    section:not(.main) > section { @include grid-fluid-span(6, $fluidGridColumnWidth1200, $fluidGridGutterWidth1200); }
    #page-body { @include grid-fluid-span(8, $fluidGridColumnWidth1200, $fluidGridGutterWidth1200); }
    #page-sidebar { @include grid-fluid-span(4, $fluidGridColumnWidth1200, $fluidGridGutterWidth1200); }
}
```

Best,